# Can't add git submodule when specified as a relative path

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to add a submodule to my git repo, and I'm getting this error in return:

```
remote origin does not have a url defined in .git/config
```

any ideas about what this might be? I tried googling for it but only one vague link comes up.

I'm doing this:

```
git submodule add ../extern/Lib1 lib
```

I'm expecting this to create a submodule `lib/Lib1`
I'm aware that this will only create a reference and that I then have to update/init (not crystal clear on this part, haven't gotten that far; I'm just learning the submodule command).

Comment: Just completed my answer with additional suggestions

Comment: I think the absolute path works here only because your `extern/Lib1` Git repo ... does not have a "remote origin does not have a url defined in `.git/config`" ;). Some investigation in that .git/config is in order.

Comment: not sure what you mean. I just looked at extern/Lib1's .git/config and all it has is the [core] section:
repositoryformatversion=0,filemode=true,bare=false,legalrefupdates=true

Comment: Just added an example about where exactly that "remote origin" should be defined. See my edited answer.

Comment: Your last comment made me re-read the git submodule man page. I have edited my answer for a more exact location of the relevant `.git/config` file.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Does `../extern/Lib1` refer to a Git repository?
If it does not, Git wouldn't know how to have the Git repo URL to its `.gitmodule`
Also, try:

- with the destination `lib` *not* already existing (even empty)
- with an absolute path instead of a relative path (you can use a relative one, but just in case, it is worth a try here)

Some good sources on submodules are:

- [chapter 8 of Git User's manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#submodules)
- [Wiki page on Git Submodule Tutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial)
  and of course
- [Git submodule man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

---

Since only the absolute path works here, it means the relative path need a reference to be compared against.
That reference is the "remote origin" which should be in your `DirName/NewRepo_withSubmodules/.git/config` file, like so:

```
$ cat .git/config
    ...
    [remote "origin"]
    url = /path/to/DirName/NewRepo_withSubmodules/.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    ...
```

If you do have that section in `../DirName/NewRepo_withSubmodules/.git/config` file, you should be able to add `../Extern/Lib1` as a submodule using a relative path.

All the above is inspired from the following section of the git submodule man page:

> `<repository>` is the URL of the new submodule's origin repository.
> This may be either an absolute URL, or (if it begins with `./` or `../`), **the location relative to the superproject's *`origin`* repository**.

So if `NewRepo_withSubmodules` is a local Git repo which has just been created (and has of course no "origin"), an artificial "remote origin" ought to be defined (even if the origin points to itself), if only to allow relative URL for other submodule repositories to be used.

---

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) will improve the detection of the default origin of a submodule.

See [commit d1b3b81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1b3b81aabf91ce654b043b00aa72721a777c84c) (25 Feb 2017) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ae900eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae900ebd71b58c12356674228ce99e6673da3dec), 10 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### `submodule init`: warn about falling back to a local path

As [now documented](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ae900ebd71b58c12356674228ce99e6673da3dec/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L74-L88):

> `<repository>` is the URL of the new submodule's origin repository.
> This may be either an absolute URL, or (if it begins with `./` or `../`), the location relative to the superproject's default remote repository
> (Please note that to specify a repository '`foo.git`' which is located right next to a superproject '`bar.git`', you'll have to use '`../foo.git`' instead of '`./foo.git`' - as one might expect when following the rules for relative URLs - because the evaluation of relative URLs in Git is identical to that of relative directories).
>
> The default remote is the remote of the remote tracking branch of the current branch.
> If no such remote tracking branch exists or the `HEAD` is detached, "`origin`" is assumed to be the default remote.
> If the superproject doesn't have a default remote configured, the superproject is its own authoritative upstream and the current.
> Working directory is used instead.

---

Git 2.20 (Q4 2018) improves local path support for submodules.

See [commit e0a862f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0a862fdaf7628ceba4ea290b91ffd5d3c46b75b) (16 Oct 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3fc8522](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3fc8522e68c00c899567c2877bb71aff75d9df3e), 06 Nov 2018)</sup>

> ### `submodule helper`: convert relative URL to absolute URL if needed

> The submodule helper `update_clone` called by "`git submodule update`", clones submodules if needed.
> As submodules used to have the URL indicating if they were active, the step to resolve relative URLs was done in the "`submodule init`" step. Nowadays, submodules can be configured active without calling an explicit `init`, e.g. via configuring `submodule.active`.
>
> When trying to obtain submodules that are set active this way, we'll fallback to the URL found in the `.gitmodules`, which may be relative to the superproject, but we do not resolve it, yet:
>
> ```bash
> git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
> cd gerrit && grep url .gitmodules
>   url = ../plugins/codemirror-editor
>   ...
> git config submodule.active .
> git submodule update
>   fatal: repository '../plugins/codemirror-editor' does not exist
>   fatal: clone of '../plugins/codemirror-editor' into submodule path '/tmp/gerrit/plugins/codemirror-editor' failed
>   Failed to clone 'plugins/codemirror-editor'. Retry scheduled
>   [...]
>   fatal: clone of '../plugins/codemirror-editor' into submodule path '/tmp/gerrit/plugins/codemirror-editor' failed
>   Failed to clone 'plugins/codemirror-editor' a second time, aborting
>   [...]
> ```
>
> To resolve the issue, factor out the function that resolves the relative URLs in "`git submodule init`" (in the submodule helper in the `init_submodule` function) and call it at the appropriate place in the `update_clone` helper.

---

"[`git submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9cd234e6465ab2bea5c402f0d9ee1495501250ef/Documentation/git-submodule.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule))</sup> code trusted the data coming from the config (and the in-tree `.gitmodules` file) too much without validating, leading to `NULL` dereference if the user mucks with a repository (e.g. when `submodule.<name>.url` is removed).
This has been corrected with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

See [commit fbc806a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbc806acd106ee1c05fd0a0a83b7c59aa79629d8) (24 May 2023) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9cd234e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9cd234e6465ab2bea5c402f0d9ee1495501250ef), 20 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/submodule--helper.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbc806acd106ee1c05fd0a0a83b7c59aa79629d8): handle missing submodule URLs
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Tribo Dar</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> In [e0a862f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0a862fdaf7628ceba4ea290b91ffd5d3c46b75b) ("submodule helper: convert relative URL to absolute URL if needed", 2018-10-16, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3fc8522e68c00c899567c2877bb71aff75d9df3e) listed in [batch #9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8858448bb49332d353febc078ce4a3abcc962efe)), `prepare_to_clone_next_submodule()` lost the ability to handle URL-less submodules, due to a change from:
>
> ```
> if (repo_get_config_string_const(the_repostiory, sb.buf, &url))
>     url = sub->url;
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> if (repo_get_config_string_const(the_repostiory, sb.buf, &url)) {
>     if (starts_with_dot_slash(sub->url) ||
>         starts_with_dot_dot_slash(sub->url)) {
>             /* ... */
>         }
> }
> ```
>
> ,which will segfault when `sub->url` is `NULL`, since both `starts_with_dot_slash()` does not guard its arguments as non-NULL.
>
> Guard the checks to both of the above functions by first checking whether `sub->url` is non-NULL.
> There is no need to check whether `sub` itself is `NULL`, since we already perform this check earlier in `prepare_to_clone_next_submodule()`.
>
> By adding a NULL-ness check on `sub->url`, we'll fall into the '`else`' branch, setting `url` to `sub->url` (which is NULL).
> Before attempting to invoke `git submodule--helper clone`, check whether `url` is `NULL`, and `die()` if it is.

Comment: yep it does.  
the ./lib folder is empty tho (in "git submodule add ../extern/Lib1 lib")

Comment: damn. ok, so the absolute path worked, the relative does not...  
this is not mentioned anywhere (I've been reading tutorials for hours and they all use web URL's as examples).    
the problem with this is when someone else clones my repos, and does not have the correct dir nesting, the 'submodule init/update' wont work for them...  

any ideas?

thanks Von, appreciate it

Comment: will do as you suggest. question: doesnt this just move the absolute path from the super-repo (one into which we're placing the submodule)  into the repo referenced by the submodule? in my case both the superrepo and the referenced repo (from inside the submodule) are in the same master dir DirName (DirName/extern/Lib1 & DirName/NewRepo_withSubmodules). So I would prefer to be able to move that master dir (DirName) around without configs inside it breaking.

Comment: Good question, which made me revisit the `.git/config` file location. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks for your time Vic. Im giving it all a shot right now. will approve the answer as the final one when it all goes through in my test setup.

Comment: great! so it worked. in order to use relative paths to the external submodule I had to first do the following (on a fresh - noncloned repo): "git remote add origin .." and then "git submodule add ../extern/LibName lib". thanks again Vic!

Comment: @deepblue: you're welcome:) And you are almost there ;) It's Von*C* , not Von. But anyway, I learn some more on this submodule topic answering your question, so you can call me whatever you want.

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer that finally makes me understand why `git submodule update` insists on using HTTPS when I want it to use SSH. So I'm going to rename my old HTTPS `origin` to `origin-https` and rename my current `origin-ssh` to `origin`, then do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52656557) to ensure all my refs point at the SSH one. I'm only keeping the HTTPS one around 'Just In Case' anyway...

Answer (score 5):

I was trying the same thing, and found the following 'seems to have worked:

I have (on windows):

`D:/phd/analyses
    /analysis1/ #This is an existing repository
    /analysis2/ #another existing repository
    /analysis3.tex
    /analysis4.tex
    ...
    /analysisN.tex`

`analysis1.tex ... analysisN.tex` contain ideas I've not worked on yet ('stubs, say), and `analysis1/` and `analysis2/` are things I am working on (and hence have code, tex, ... in them). Once I get around to working on the other analyses, they will get moved to their own folders and hence their own repositories.

What I did was (in git bash in analyses):

```
git init
git add *.tex
git remote add self .
git submodule add self:/analysis2/.git analysis2
git submodule add self:/analysis5/.git analysis5
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

This seems to have worked.

`D:/phd/analyses/.git/config` looks like it should, and `.gitmodules` looks like:

```
[submodule "analysis2"]
    path = analysis2
    url = self:analysis2/.git
[submodule "analysis5"]
    path = analysis5
    url = self:analysis5/.git
```

Regards,
Simon Knapp

Comment: Doesn't work for me (on Linux). It tries to access the computer `self` over the Internet.

Comment: also does not work on darwin: …


`[852]$ git submodule add  -b myBranch self:../relativeRepo
Cloning into relativeRepo...`  
ssh: Could not resolve hostname self: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`  
    Clone of 'self:../relativeRepo' into submodule path 'relativeRepo' failed

Answer (score 1):

*(I've summarized just the solution here. Credit goes to VonC.)*

In the containing repository (say `containing.git/`), `git` interprets relative paths as relative to the `origin` remote, which is not defined. We want it to be relative to the `containing.git/` directory, so run

```
git remote add origin ..
```

(Not sure why it's `..` rather than `.`.)

Now you can add the sub-module:

```
git submodule add ../extern/Lib1 lib
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - it still tried to look up `../extern/Lib1` in the local path. I had to do `git remote rename myrem origin`, then `git submodule add ../extern/Lib1 lib`, then `git remote rename origin myrem` and `git submodule foreach git remote rename origin myrem`