# You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree

Tags: vim

I'm trying to install [utilsnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715).

When I type:

```
cd ~/.vim/ 
git submodule add https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips bundle/ultisnips
```

I get this message:

```
You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
```

Why? How can I avoid it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a submodule to a sub-directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035895/how-do-i-add-a-submodule-to-a-sub-directory)

Comment: @glts: I looked it before posting. But it doesn't answer my issue.

Comment: It's the same question. Your `~/.vim` is not the root of your Git repo (is it a symlink?). Try `cd ..` followed by the `git submodule` command until you find the "toplevel of the working tree".

Comment: In fact there aren't git repo that's why I can't do it. Thank's for help. I will try the second way with `bzr` command

Comment: If there is no Git repo, why are you trying to add a Git submodule? Install it manually, you don't need `git submodule` to install Vim plugins, just unzip in your `~/.vim`.

Comment: That's what I did after seeing that's not a git repo. I follow Using Bzr install (in http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). Next when i type    `:helptags ~/.vim/ultisnips_rep/doc` or `:help UltiSnips` on vim nothing appear

Comment: Solved by using `:BundleInstall 'UltiSnips'` comand on vim

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `.vim` directory might not be a `git` directory.  To make it a `git` directory simply:

```
git init
```

Then you can run:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips bundle/ultisnips
```

Answer (score 19):

You might be running the command from a subdirectory. Make sure you are in the directory same level as the .git directory.

Comment: .git is not be located there