# git submodule update - why from toplevel

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've always been puzzled by this:

```
$ git submodule
You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
```

Why do I need to run it from the top level directory? Is it a technical reason, or just because of a convention / possible flaw ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: since git 1.8.4 (August 2013), and [commit 091a6eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/091a6eb0feed820a43663ca63dc2bc0bb247bbae), you don't have to be at top-level to run `git submodule update`.
This is because [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) has a new `--prefix` option.

```
--prefix <arg>
```

> Behave as if git rev-parse was invoked from the `<arg>` subdirectory of the working tree.
>   Any relative filenames are resolved as if they are prefixed by `<arg>` and will be printed in that form.

That same limitation is gone for [`git submodule add` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17401451/6309).