# Using a repo inside a repo github

Tags: git

Hi so this question has probably been asked before but since I am unsure of the terms to use I cannot find the answer. So I have a github repo A which contains data structure classes and is incomplete. I want to access it in repo B and repo C. Is there a way I can go about doing this so that i can keep updating repo A and testing it in repo B and C. Sorry for asking what i assume is a redundant question I am just unsure of what I am supposed to be searching and I keep finding things that are not related or I am not understanding as related.

Comment: Git is the tool. Github is the website. You may find submodules to be what you want. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Thanks I am using Github website sorry for the wrong tag

Comment: Not a problem, just trying to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a submodule to a sub-directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035895/how-do-i-add-a-submodule-to-a-sub-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Check out git [submodules](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial). These are basically nested repositories so you can better manage your network/repositories/code.

The link above provides a quick output-oriented guide on how you should go about setting up submodules for a repository.

For a more beginner-friendly tutorial, check out [this article](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/) instead.

Comment: Thanks the beginner friendly article is exactly what i needed