# Add submodule via relative path

Tags: git, git-submodules

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17401451/3426358) on SO- I understand that following git 1.8.4, submodules can be added from anywhere ( not just toplevel). I'm on git version 2.7.4 and when I do:

```
git submodule add ../../../functest
```

I get:

```
Relative path can only be used from the toplevel of the working tree
```

I'm in `opnfvdocs/docs/submodules`. I want to add `opnfvdocs/functest` inside `opnfvdocs/docs/submodules` such that I have relative path in `.gitmodules`

The tree structure is:

```
github.com/OPNFV
|-opnfvdocs
|-functest
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to read your link more closely... "Since the interpretation of a relative submodule URL depends on whether or not "remote.origin.url" is configured, ***explicitly block relative URLs in "git submodule add" when not at the top level of the working tree***."

Comment: So this means I have to configure `remote.origin.url` to point at `OPNFV`?

Answer (score 3):

To create a submodule at a specific path, stay at top level, and provide the path as last argument:

```
opnfvdocs$ git submodule add ../functest docs/submodules/functest
```

Comment: @flyingaura: Tested with 2.37.1, works. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: As of october 2022, you may get the error `fatal: transport 'file' not allowed`. Use `git -c protocol.file.allow=always submodule add ../functest docs/submodules/functest` instead. [Details (security implications!) here](https://vielmetti.typepad.com/logbook/2022/10/git-security-fixes-lead-to-fatal-transport-file-not-allowed-error-in-ci-systems-cve-2022-39253.html)